# Testing pdf/excel content with C#

Tags: pdf, c#, .net, microsoft-excel, quality-assurance

Our site has a good number of reports that are using `SSRS`,`Crystal` and `Excel`. We are using `C#` with Selenium `WebDriver`. I have been searching for the best practices and best ways and tools to test the content of those report. I need to test pdf/excel content or both depending on the report I am testing. I know `Selenium` does not have native support for this kind of testing. My question is what kind of tool I can integrate with `Selenium` to accomplish that. Open source preferred.

In summary:

- What tool can be integrated with Selenium C# to test pdf/excel
  content?

Comment: Do you have some more bullets? Test criteria? What to test for, what kind of results?

Comment: @Izzy not really. I just want to be able to read the content clearly

Comment: Interacting with PDF is true pain because of how they are implemented. (Using something equivelent to Selenium, with user interaction emulation wouldn't even be bad.)
On  the other hand, there are good and reliable tools to interact with excel, without having to deal with faking user actions.
No tool except UI Automation tools will work for both (eg https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753107%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
I thus suggest splitting the question into two

Comment: @Oxinabox Thanks for your valuable comment. I would do some more research and split the question. And, do you know any tool to interact with excel off-hand?

Comment: 4 years ago LinqToExcel was good. https://github.com/paulyoder/LinqToExcel

Comment: @Oxinabox Great resource. I will spend some time on this. Thanks again and if you turn your comment into an answer I will give you thumbs up for providing me this resource

Comment: I'm not happy making that into an answer. Its been to long. Also the question asks about both, it answers only one.